# Wait for google map to become available before adding map markers

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Because I need to cluster my map markers, I cannot use google maps compose.  I need to  initialize a MapView, await GoogleMap and create a ClusterManager.  I am also passing a collection of map markers into the composable, on change of those map markers I need to update my map, however a change in marker is detected and composed before my map is ready, meaning the first change to the markers collection cannot be added to that cluster manager.

Init MapView:

```
@Composable
fun rememberMapViewWithLifecycle(): MapView {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val mapView = remember {
      MapView(context)
   }

   val lifecycleObserver = rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView)
   val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
   DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
      lifecycle.addObserver(lifecycleObserver)
      onDispose {
         lifecycle.removeObserver(lifecycleObserver)
      }
   }

   return mapView
}

@Composable
private fun rememberMapLifecycleObserver(mapView: MapView): LifecycleEventObserver =
   remember(mapView) {
      LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
         when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> mapView.onCreate(Bundle())
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
            else -> throw IllegalStateException()
         }
      }
   }
```

Wait for google map, and init cluster manager:

```
@Composable
private fun Map(
   markers: List<MapItem>
) {
  var previousMarkers by remember { mutableStateOf(markers) }
  var clusterManager by remember() { mutableStateOf<ClusterManager<MapItem>?>(null)}

  // Init map here, only once
  LaunchedEffect(mapView, mapInitialized) {
     if (!mapInitialized) {
        val map = mapView.awaitMap()
        val manager = ClusterManager<MapItem>(context, map)

        map.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
        map.uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled = false

        mapInitialized = true
     }
  }

  // Detect changes in the markers collection to add/update/remove markers on map
  // Problem with this is that markers collection changes before map and
  // ClusterManager are ready. 
  LaunchedEffect(markers) {
     // add new markers
     ...
     // update markers
     ...
     // remove markers
     ...

     if (markers != previousMarker) {
        manager.cluster()
        previousMarker = markers
     }
  }
```

}

Is it possible to wait for the map and the ClusterManager to become available before processing changes to the markers collection?